# Maximum likelihood of a no-closed form density

Tags: optimization, closed-form, maximum-likelihood

Supposed we have density function $f(y_i)$ which have no closed form expression. Now can we find the estimating equation of the log likelihood of $f(y_i)$ by taking the derivative(I have tried this multiple times and failed) or we need to do optimization technique? I am asking just to make sure that either I am doing something wrong or it's usually not possible to find estimating equation by taking derivative of the log-likelihood of no closed-form density.

Comment: what do you know about $f$?

Comment: If you have the function $f$ but not a close expression (say you have a grid of values of $f(x)$) and you want to find the maximum, then simply return the maximum of the grid.

Comment: My function f is a non-linear function of grid values

Comment: If you have no closed form expression for $f$, so be it, that can be pretty common in some areas. More than likely you'll have to maximize the log-likelihood numerically or, if circumstances dictate the use of Lagrange multipliers to enforce constraints, to find stationary points. Just saw that your $f$ is defined on a grid. Smooth, local interpolation will help, and more than likely you'll find lots of local extrema, so you'll have to sort things out afterwards.